# Uninitialized constant error constant Skill:Description

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, uninitialized-constant

I am trying to make a form and submit a skill and description into a database.  I am almost done however I am getting this error after submitting my info:

```
NameError in SkillsController#create
uninitialized constant Skill::Description
```

and it points to this action in my controller:

```
def create
  @skills = Skill.new(skill_params)
  if @skills.save
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  else
    @skills = Skill.find(:all)
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

I have a private method at the bottom defining params which states:

```
private

  def skill_params
  params.require(:skill).permit(:description)
  end
```

This is the fullstack trace:

```
   activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:133:in `compute_type'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:221:in `klass'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:214:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:356:in `block in replace'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:356:in `each_char'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:356:in `replace'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:41:in `writer'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:118:in `description='
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `public_send'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/core.rb:455:in `init_attributes'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    app/controllers/skills_controller.rb:29:in `create'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
    actionview (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
    railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'

railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

and this is my schema:

```
  create_table "skills", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.string   "description"
  end
```

This is my skills/new.html.erb form:

```
<h1>Add new Skill</h1>
<%= form_tag ({action: "create"}) do %>
<p><label for="skill">Skill</label>:
<%= text_field 'skill', 'title' %></p>

<p><label for="skill_description">Description</label><br/>
<%= text_area 'skill', 'description' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end  %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'index'} %>
```

I hope I have provided enough info to solve the issue and thank you anyone who knows what to do to initialize description.  Thanks again and cheers!

index.html.erb:

```
<% if @skills.blank? %>
  <p>There are not any skills currently saved in the system.</p>
<% else %>
  <p>These are the current skills saved in our system</p>
  <ul id="skills">
    <% @skills.each do |c| %>
      <li><%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%></li>
      <li>
       <%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%>
       <b> <%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %></b>
       <b> <%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
        :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this skill??" %></b>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <p><%= link_to "Add new Skill", {:action => 'new' }%></p>
<% end %>
```

I do not have a title param available and it is causing problems.

skill.rb:

```
 class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :skill

    has_many :description
end
```

hope this new info helps! Thanks again for taking a look with me.

Comment: can you paste the content of the Skill model as well? thanks!

Comment: yes I will thank you, I am also posting my index.html.erb as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the model **skill.rb** to this:

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The `has_many` method is used to define `Relations` in the ORM context. There is no need to define the columns of the table itself. Rails get that information by itself.

You also have other issues in your `index.html.erb` and `new.html.erb` pages. You are referring to a `title` property of `skill`, but your migration does not show a `title` property.

I would recommend you delete controller, model, views, migration and data table itself (assuming that it is just a development project) and use scaffold to generate them using the command below:

```
$ bin/rails generate scaffold Skill title:string description:text
```

Please note that `$` is not part of the command, its the prompt in your terminal.

[Read up more on rails command line here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

Comment: It seems like it is a better way to go however when I rake db:migrate:redo I get a SQL exception saying table "skills" already exists.  Any ideas on how to remove it and re rake?  I tried rake db:migrate VERSION = 0 but it did not help.  Thanks again I think your way is still the best so I will upvote and select as answer

Comment: Remember I said delete the data table too. Now that you have already deleted the old migration file, you will have to delete the `skills` table from the database manually. The commands will slightly vary depending on which database you are using.

Comment: and you mean delete the tables in my schema?

Comment: it seems like my schema is getting generated by something else because its contents are only::::::::::::::::  create_table "skills", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.string   "description"
  end

Comment: title is nowhere in there=(

Comment: Not the schema, delete the table from the database, like MySQL or Postgres. What database are u using? You can tell from database.yml which database you are using.

Comment: MySQLite3 is the db I am useing.

Comment: Found it! thank you San, I got my DB going smoothly! Thank you for showing me the power of the rails command line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better use `form_for`. There are no `skill_params` returning if you build the form that way.

`form_tag` is better for no model forms.

Try like this:

```
# skills_controller
def new
  @skill = Skill.new
end


# new.html.erb
<%= form_for @skill do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
   # Other fields and tags...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I remove the create action too?

Comment: and I got this error:::::ArgumentError in Skills#new
Showing /app/views/skills/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: Please, make sure that you declared @skill in your controller action new as written above.